# Rococo collator running on aws eks fails and restart every few minutes

Tags: polkadot, rococo, collator

I have a rococo collator running on aws eks that keeps failing, here are the logs:

```
2023-04-23 01:49:19 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x3865…1210), finalized #0 (0x3865…1210), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="candidate-validation-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "candidate-validation", source: Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty.")) }
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] Overseer exited with error err=Generated(SubsystemStalled("availability-store-subsystem"))
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="dispute-coordinator-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "dispute-coordinator", source: SubsystemReceive(Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty."))) }
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] Essential task `overseer` failed. Shutting down service.    
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="approval-voting-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "approval-voting", source: Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty.")) }
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="bitfield-signing-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "bitfield-signing", source: Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty.")) }
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] err=Subsystem(Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty.")))
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="availability-recovery-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "availability-recovery", source: Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty.")) }
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="statement-distribution-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "statement-distribution", source: SubsystemReceive(Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty."))) }
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] Failed to receive a message from Overseer, exiting err=Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty."))
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="network-bridge-rx-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "network-bridge", source: SubsystemError(Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty."))) }
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="chain-api-subsystem" err=FromOrigin { origin: "chain-api", source: Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty.")) }
2023-04-23 01:49:22 [Relaychain] subsystem exited with error subsystem="runtime-api-subsystem" err=Generated(Context("Signal channel is terminated and empty."))
Error: Service(Other("Essential task failed."))
```

The parachain is not producing blocks yet.

These are the parameters I'm passing to the binary:

```
--collator --base-path /var/www/collator-data/ --force-authoring --ws-port 9946 --ws-external --rpc-external --rpc-cors all --rpc-methods unsafe --chain /var/www/substrate/resources/collator-raw-spec.json -- --execution wasm --base-path /var/www/relay-data/ --chain /var/www/substrate/resources/rococo.json --port 30333 --ws-port 9944 --ws-external --rpc-external --rpc-cors all --rpc-methods unsafe --wasm-execution Compiled --pruning 10000
```

I've tried running it in different instance types, even c6id.2xlarge instance, but with the same results.

The strange thing is that I'm also running a collator for polkadot and that one is running without any issues.

The node client version being used is: v0.9.38, the runtime on v0.9.27, as we want to test the upgrade on rococo before performing it on polkadot

Does anyone know what could be the cause of the issue?

UPDATE:
I've create the following issue: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/7200

Thanks

Comment: Is this on `polkadot-v0.9.37`?

Comment: No, on polkadot-v0.9.38

Comment: Try upgrading to polkadot-v0.9.39 as noted [here](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/issues/910#issuecomment-1512536295) and see if the error goes away.

Comment: I've upgraded the node client to v0.9.40, but still have the same issue, any other ideas of what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Okay, then please create a Github issue [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues). You can reference this closed [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/6624) as well. Please update this post once you have done so. Thanks!